# I'm programming a game. each of my functions work fine independently but not together

Tags: python

New to coding and trying to make a game. The game is Cows and Bulls and it's similar to Mastermind.
Here is my code, I can run them all independently but I'm getting stuck with the play_game function. It just runs indefinitely and gets stuck on the how_many_bulls function until I manually stop it. Any help would be really appreciated, as I'm currently at a loss

```
def generate_secret():
  secret=''
  x=str(int(random.random()*10))
  while len(secret)<4:
    x=str(int(random.random()*10))
    if x not in secret:
      secret=secret+x
  return secret

def how_many_bulls(answer, guess):
  answer=secret
  guess=player_guess
  a=0
  bulls=0
  while a < 4:
    if guess[a]==secret[a]:
      bulls=bulls+1
      a=a+1
  return bulls

def how_many_cows(answer,guess):
  cows=0
  repeat_list=[]
  b=0
  c=0
  while b < 4:
    while c < 4:
      if guess[b]==answer[c] and guess[b]==answer[b]:
        c=c+1
      elif guess[b]==answer[c]:
        for number in guess[b]:
          if number in  '1234567890' and not (number in repeat_list):
            repeat_list.append(number)
            cows=len(repeat_list)
        c=c+1
      elif c < 4:
        c=c+1
      else:
        Break
    c=0
    b=b+1
  return cows

def play_game():
  bulls=0
  guesses=0
  while bulls < 4:
    player_guess=input("Guess your 4 digit number!")
    guesses=guesses+1
    how_many_bulls(answer,guess)
    how_many_cows(answer,guess)
  if bulls == 4:
    print('Congrats!, That was the correct guess,',guess,'.' 'It took you' ,guesses, 'tries.')
  else:
    print('Nice try, you got' ,bulls, 'bulls. and' ,cows, 'cows.')
    bulls=0
    cows=0

play_game()
```

the error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-51076e9b4cab> in <module>()
----> 1 play_game()

1 frames
<ipython-input-34-15929b8be5b5> in how_many_bulls(answer, guess)
     14   bulls=0
     15   while a < 4:
---> 16     if guess[a]==answer[a]:
     17       bulls=bulls+1
     18       a=a+1

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: looks like the condition is never met

Comment: Please correct the indentation. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` means someone cancelled the program while it was running. That's not an error message from your program failing on its own, but a user pressing ctrl+c.

Comment: By contrast, if you have an endless loop, your best bet is to instrument your code with logging statements; the stack traces you get will be different every time depending on which line it happens to be on when the interrupt handler triggers, so it doesn't tell us anything useful at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm aware, i'm interrupting it because it runs forever, i included it to show where it's doing that. I'm not sure what a logging statement is, but i'll look it up

Comment: Sure, but that's a sample size of 1. Whereas if you, say, used a sampling profiler, you'd have a count of how many each individual line was caused, so there'd be enough to actually determine the scope.

Comment: @aws_apprentice, agreed, but if I run the function separate it is met and works fine.

Comment: As for what "a logging statement" is -- the simplest kind is just a bunch of `print()`s; as in, `print("Starting how_many_cows loop with a=%s, b=%s, c=%s" % (a, b, c,))`; place them strategically, and you can get a very good idea of what's wrong just by reading the output.

Comment: @quamrana I think it's correct now.

Comment: The indentation is incorrect. Nothing more!

Comment: BTW, this code certainly doesn't qualify as a [mre] right now -- it doesn't successfully *reproduce* the error because it's incomplete (missing `import`s if nothing else), and it's not *minimal* because it includes code that's unrelated to your problem.

Comment: You made no changes to the indentation. The problem is that the a=a+1 line is indented too much.

Comment: @quamrana THANK YOU! that's exactly it...I'm still getting errors but at least I know what was causing that one.

Comment: I’m sorry that took so long. Feel free to create a new question if you can isolate your error.

Comment: I agree with @CharlesDuffy.